# AIMMS how to take two instances of an index

Tags: subset, aimms

I am working on my thesis and I was wondering the following:

I have a set N with index i.
Then, based on the elements of set N, I want to create a set that contains certain pairs of (i, i'), where i and i' are both from set N.

How can I do this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, just add another index i2 to set N. This way you'll have a set N with index i and i2. Now you can define for example `MyPairs(i,i2)` where i and i2 are elements of N.